# Python: How to print 100.0 instead of 100 in float

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am solving a Python exercise about class:

> Define a class called Bank that accepts the name you want associated
>   with your bank account in a string, and a float that represents the
>   amount of money in the account. The constructor should initialize two
>   instance variables from those inputs: name and amt. Add a string
>   method so that when you print an instance of Bank, you see “Your
>   account, [name goes here], has [start_amt goes here] dollars.” Create
>   an instance of this class with "Bob" as the name and 100.0 as the
>   amount. Save this to the variable t1.

I wrote the following:

```
class Bank:
def __init__(self, name, amt):
    self.name = name
    self.amt = amt

def __str__(self):
    return "Your account, {}, has {} dollars.".format(self.name, self.amt)

 t1 = Bank("Bob", 100.0)
 print(t1)
```

And the result I get is "`Your account, Bob, has 100 dollars.`"

But the correct answer is "`Your account, Bob, has 100.0 dollars.`"

How can I do to fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change your `format`:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "Your account, {0}, has {1:.1f} dollars.".format(self.name, self.amt)
```

Check out the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Comment: It works! Thank you for providing the reference that I can learn more about it!

Comment: @RoyWang No problem. Be sure to accept the answer if it helped! See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Or *hack* it:

```
return "Your account, {}, has {}.0 dollars.".format(self.name, self.amt)
```

Or use `float`:

```
return "Your account, {}, has {} dollars.".format(self.name, float(self.amt))
```

Comment: @RoyWang Since you've got 15 rep don't forget to up-vote my answer.